# geolocation and a floorplan - javascript marauders map

Tags: javascript, geolocation

If someone gave you point A(lat,lon) and point B(lat,lon) on a floor plan image, and you have the width and height of the floorplan image, can you then use geolocation to track where they are as they walk around?

Are there any projects you know of that attempt to solve this?

Comment: Do you mean something like an "inhouse-GPS"? I don't think this has something to do with the tag javascript and it's not that easy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with geolocation in JavaScript, but if you can map locations in real life to your image then it should work fine.